# Issue: string manipulation with links inside

Tags: macros, hyperref, links, xstring, lettrine

I have defined a new command `\openintro` which I call at every chapter of my work. This command basically constructs a lettrine sentence, like the image below (don't bother with text style):

```
\openintro{This is a working test}
```

[image]

I use some commands of `xstring` package to cut/split the text to match the desired effect with lettrine. However, I'm getting some errors when using `\ref{label}` inside the command.

```
\openintro{This is a NOT working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}
```

The problem is related to the `hyperref` package, with links enabled. The command `\StrBefore` presents some errors when facing a link in the string. If I disable `hyperref`, there is no problem when using `\ref`. But I need to use `hyperref`. Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue? Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xstring,lettrine}

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  linktoc=all,
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=red
}%

\newcommand{\openintro}[1]{%
  \def\firsttwowords{}%
  \def\firstword{}%
  \def\firstwordsplit{}%
  \def\secondword{}%
  \def\firstletter{}%
  \def\remainingtext{}%
  \def\charcount{}%
  \StrBefore[2]{#1}{ }[\firsttwowords]% get the first two words
  \StrBefore[1]{\firsttwowords}{ }[\firstword]% get the first word
  \StrGobbleLeft{\firstword}{1}[\firstwordsplit]% del the first letter of first word
  \StrBehind[1]{\firsttwowords}{ }[\secondword]% get only the second word
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]% get the first letter of first word
  \StrLen{\firsttwowords}[\charcount]% count the number of characters of first two words
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{\charcount}[\remainingtext]% del the number of characters on the left of the whole sentence
  \lettrine{\firstletter}{\firstwordsplit~\secondword}~\textit{\remainingtext}\\[1PC]%
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\openintro{This is a NOT working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}

\section{Hi there}\label{mylabel}

\end{document}
```

And the error:

```
! Use of \@xs@StrBefore@@ doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.36 ...s a NOT working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}

! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.36 ...s a NOT working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expansion of `\ref...` leads to the error. However, the `xstring` knows the `\noexpandarg` macro, preventing the the expansion of the argument of the main input string to `xstring` macros, but after the first operation expansion must be enabled again, using `\expandarg`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xstring,lettrine}

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  linktoc=all,
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=red
}%

\newcommand{\openintro}[1]{%
  \def\firsttwowords{}%
  \def\firstword{}%
  \def\firstwordsplit{}%
  \def\secondword{}%
  \def\firstletter{}%
  \def\remainingtext{}%
  \def\charcount{}%
  \noexpandarg%
  \StrBefore[2]{#1}{ }[\firsttwowords]% get the first two words
  \expandarg% Now expand again
  \StrBefore[1]{\firsttwowords}{ }[\firstword]% get the first word
  \StrGobbleLeft{\firstword}{1}[\firstwordsplit]% del the first letter of first word
  \StrBehind[1]{\firsttwowords}{ }[\secondword]% get only the second word
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]% get the first letter of first word
  \StrLen{\firsttwowords}[\charcount]% count the number of characters of first two words
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{\charcount}[\remainingtext]% del the number of characters on the left of the whole sentence
  \lettrine{\firstletter}{\firstwordsplit~\secondword}~\textit{\remainingtext}\\[1PC]%
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\openintro{This is a NOT working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}

\section{Hi there}\label{mylabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The secret was \noexpandarg! Thank you! :)

Comment: @CarlosViegas: Thank you. I am thinking about if this could be done easier

Comment: Well, I made it in a hurry. Maybe with a little bit more time it could be done easier. But my knowledge to simplify it is a bit limited. It was the first thing I've tried and has worked. If you have some spare time, feel free to improve it. I'll appreciate it. But for me it is good the way it is. Thank you one more time.

Comment: @CarlosViegas: Sorry,  my comment was misunderstandable. I meant, if it's possible to bypass the `\noexpandarg` stuff.

Comment: Oh, no problem. But I don't have the proper knowledge to answer that! :)

Comment: There's a spurious space somewhere: you can clearly see a double space between “it” and ”is”.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, that's true and I noted it yesterday already, but it's in the OP's screen shot too, so the source must be somewhere in the concatening of strings, but I had no time to address this so far

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me as overcomplicated. Why there are the `\StrBefore` etc. processing? Why do you need `letrine` package? You can do the same by this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  linktoc=all, 
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=red
}%

\def\openintro#1{\openintroA #1 \end}
\def\openintroA#1#2 #3 #4\end{\par
   \setbox0=\hbox{\fontsize{27}{27}\selectfont#1\/}%
   \hangindent=\wd0 \advance\hangindent by0pt \hangafter=-2
   \noindent \hskip-\hangindent\vbox to0pt{\kern-6pt\box0\vss}%
   {\uppercase{#2 #3} \it#4\unskip}%
   \medskip
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\openintro{This is a working test due to~\ref{mylabel}}

\section{Hi there}\label{mylabel}

\end{document}
```

Many problems occur because people don't know that things can be done more simple.

Edit: Due to David's comment I modified the `\openitroA` definition in order to the behavior will be similar to letrine usage for texts with more lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I didn't think about the design of this "intro" when there will be more lines. I corrected this. I still don't know exactly the desired design but we can show that the design can be declared by \hbox/\vbox arithmetic at few lines of the code. What we need is to know TeX only.

Comment: @wipet Thanks for your solution. It is simpler when compared to mine. However, lettrine allows me to configure the text position easily, in contrast to yours which demands more trial and error (for me at least, since my knowledge of latex2e is a bit limited). Take a look at the image and see the comparison between both (please notice the red dots highlighting the position of the text): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16521384/lettrine2.png
I know it is possible to edit your code to achieve the desired effect, but for me with lettrine is simpler. Anyway, I appreciate your effort. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlosViegas You are not right when you write that your knowledge is a bit limited. Your knowledge is very extensive, because you know the language of letrine, language of second package, language of third package, ..., language of the last package. But I know only one typesetting language: language of TeX. And I want to show you that this knowledge is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question, by using part of the code provided by @wipet and lettrine (since it is easier to manipulate the text styling). Instead of using the whole string manipulation of my first question, I just use the following code (which replaces the entire `\newcommand{\openintro}`):

```
\def\openintro#1{\openintroA #1 \end}
\def\openintroA#1#2 #3 #4\end{%
      \lettrine{#1}{#2~#3}~\textit{#4}%
}
```

Once again, I should say thanks to @ChristianHupfer, @wipet and @DavidCarlisle for the help.

Comment: I still think that typing `\openintro{T}{his is} a working test` is much better.

Comment: @egreg So `\lettrine{T}{his is} a working test` is better. However, I decided to create `\openintro` just to avoid splitting the text manually, for faster typing purposes!

Comment: What if you have an accented character as the first in the chapter? What if you decide that an overlong first word should be left alone instead of using two words? How do you accommodate initial quotes? How many chapters do you have that require `\openintro`? Just this macro is long to type, I don't think using better syntax is so burdensome.

Comment: I'm using this for a specific purpose: simple text in the beginning of chapter. There are not considered any special characters, like quotes, symbols or accents (I know this is an issue with openintro/lettrine commands). If I want to deal individually with some words (as you suggested, long words) I rather use `\lettrine` command instead. However, you pointed out some interesting situations to consider... :)

Comment: To type `\openintro{}` is quicker than `\lettrine{}{} \textit{}` due to auto-completion of text editor.

Comment: @egreg What in wipet's code avoids the same problem? That is, why does combining that code with `\lettrine` create the problem?

Comment: @cfr The code just splits the input into pieces: the first letter is used for the lettrine, the rest of the first word together with the second word is typeset in small caps, what remains in italics. In wipet's answer there's no use of `\lettrine` (which of course does much more than that quick code).